# How to select a span with multiple classes and placed inside an anchor?

Tags: jquery, anchor, html

I'm in a situation where I need to bind a click event to a span (placed inside an achor having multiple classes) based on the classes applied to it.

**For eg:**

UPDATE: Added the html eg below

```
<div class="c0 c">
    <a class="c1 c2">
    <span class="c3 c4"></span>Anchor_Text
    </a>
</div>
```

Now I'm binding a click event as below:

```
$('span.c3.c4').click(function (e) { alert("clicked!"); });
```

The above jQuery code doesnt work. However if I use the classes on anchor to bind the click event, it works. Please see below:

```
$(.c1').click(function (e) { alert("clicked!"); });

$(.c2').click(function (e) { alert("clicked!"); });
```

Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATED: Please find the html example updated within the Q now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple classes should be selected like this:

```
$('span.c3.c4').parents('a').click(function (e) { alert("clicked!"); });
```

See a working demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/JeG3A/

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply Ben. Just realized that $('span.c3.c4').click(function (e) { alert("clicked!"); }); as well as the solution proposed by you works fine only when I click on the span portion of the link. However, when I click on the link text itsel, it doesnt work. I've also tried a.c3 & a.c4 as suggested, but that didnt work either.

Comment: Post your HTML structure please, because it's not clear how it's structured.

Comment: Updated the Q with html structure

Comment: OK, so you want the whole thing (as in the `<a>`) to be clickable?

Comment: yes and is it possible to make it working by just using the span class?

Comment: Perfect, that works as expected. Really appreciate your help Ben. Thank you so much!