# How to use a not selector with multiple span classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, html

***EXTENSION TO MY PREVIOUS Q*** 
[How to select a span with multiple classes and placed inside an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506319/how-to-select-a-span-with-multiple-classes-and-placed-inside-an-anchor)

** Adding an extension to this, I would like to add a class that needs to be ignored from the click event. hence I used below code which doesnt work. Any help will be appreciated!

```
$('span.c3, span.c4:not(.c5)').parents('a').click(function (e) {
            alert("clicked!");
   });
```

I've also tried using span.c5 in the not selector but that doesnt work either :(

Please find the html change below:

```
<div class="c0 c">
        <a class="c1 c2">
        <span class="c3 c4 c5"></span>Anchor_Text
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), which will filter all the elements you selected:

```
$('span.c3, span.c4').not('.c5').parents('a').click(function (e) {
    alert("clicked!");
});
```

BTW, are you sure what you want is [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)? I think what you really want is [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCNKg/

---

**Update**: Since you mentioned in the comments that you have to use the `:not` selector because you're using event delegation, you'll have to either add `:not` to *every* selector, or just add the following filter to your script:

```
$.expr[':'].any = $.expr.createPseudo(function( selector ) {
    return function (el) {
        return $.find.matches(selector, [el]).length > 0;
    }
});
```

This adds the [`:any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:any) selector to jQuery/Sizzle (I based it off of [this jQuery feature request](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/feature-req-any-selector-filter), but updated it so that it works with [the new Sizzle selector engine used by jQuery since version 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624345/getting-the-match-object-in-a-custom-filter-selector-in-jquery-1-8)).

Once you have that filter included, you can use `:any` in your selectors, which'll work nicely with `:not`:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'span:any(.c3, .c4):not(.c5)', function (e) {
    alert("clicked!");
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCNKg/1/

Comment: Thanks Joseph. using .not() worked! I'll try evaluating both the properties and test it out in different scenario's to see which one suits best. appreciate your response!

Comment: but how to use .not() with $('body').on("click", ".c1, .c2", function () {
      alert("clicked!");        }
    })

Comment: @EvolvingTechie - You can't. In that case, you'll have to explicitly une the `:not` selector on each one of your selectors `".c1:not(.c5), .c2:not(.c5)"`. Or, just check for `hasClass('c5')` in your callback, and return early.

Comment: Awesome, using :not selector on each one of the existing selectors work. I'll also try to use hasClass. Thanks so much!

Comment: @EvolvingTechie - I added an easier solution for use the `:not` selector. Check out my update.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function, rather than the selector. For example:

```
$('span.c3, span.c4').not('.c5').parents('a').click(function (e) {
    alert("clicked!");
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SNHSH/).

Comment: +1 Using [`:any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3aany) would have been *so* much easier. I wish jQuery supported this. Check out the update to my answer. Do you think we could somehow get this into the Sizzle core. Nobody [on this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/feature-req-any-selector-filter) seems to realize how useful this is for event delegation.